# Assignment operator inside if clause assigns value and performs check?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I noticed something whilst debugging my code.

```
if(array.length=5){
    console.log("it's 5 units long");
}
```

This not only makes the array size 5(assuming it performs the assignment every time) but it also performs the check in the if, resulting in a console output. Is this normal behaviour in Javascript and is this a valid shorthand for any real scenario?

Comment: Yes it is. because the final value inside the if statement is the length of the array after assignment, which will be 5. In javascript, every number is considered to be true except 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of an assignment expression is the new value. Your code is equivalent to:

```
array.length = 5;
if (5) {
    console.log("it's 5 units long");
}
```

And `5` is a [truthy value](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), so the condition passes.

> The following values are always falsy:
>
> - `false`
> - `0` (zero)
> - `""` (empty string)
> - `null`
> - `undefined`
> - `NaN` (a special `Number` value meaning Not-a-Number!)
>
> All other values are truthy, including `"0"` (zero in quotes), `"false"` (false in quotes), empty functions, empty arrays, and empty objects.

I can contrive scenarios where this would be useful, but generally, no, it's not useful. At the very least, it's bad style, and *shouldn't* be used even if it can be.